# CSS how to create css for a table by id?

Tags: css, html-table

I'm not exactly sure how to work this question, so I hope I can example it below.

I basically have a few tables in my page.  And for each table I want a different CSS class.  I'm extremely new at writing css so i'm not sure how to say I want tableA width to be 70% and tableB width to be 60px.  To make it more complicated I have two different columns with iD's of columnA and ColumnB.  I want columnA text to be styled different than column b.   below is my html, can someone post a quick example of how to specify classes for tables.

I really want this all to be handled in my css file, not in declaring each style inside of the table.  The tables are dynamic.

```html
<table id="tableA">
        <tr>
            <td id="columnA">
            I want arial font here
            </td>
            <td id="columnB">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <table id="tableB">
        <tr>
            <td id="columnC">
            This should just be bold
            </td>
            <td id="ColumnD">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: How would you handle such situation if you were doing OOP?

Answer (score 4):

You can not use ID more than once in a single dynamically rendered page, But you can use Class multiple times.
You can target your tables data (`<td>`) neglecting the IDs in every column.

```
#tableA tr td:nth-child(1) {
    font-family: arial
}
#tableA tr td:nth-child(2) {
    font-sytle: bold;
}
#tableB tr td:nth-child(1){
   font-weight: bold;
}
#tableB tr td:nth-child(2){
   font-family: arial;
}
#tableB tr td:nth-child(3){
   font-weight : bold
}
```

You can even target every second column like this

```
#tableA tr td:nth-child(2n){
   font-weight : bold
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no CSS classes. The class concept is an HTML concept, and CSS has just class selectors—which you cannot use unless the HTML markup has `class` attributes. Here you do not need class selectors, since you can use `id` selectors like `#tableA`. The example styling described in the question can be achieved as follows (borders added just to show the widths of tables):

```css
#tableA { width: 70%; }
#tableB { width: 60px; }
#columnA { font-family: Arial; }
#columnC { font-weight: bold; }
table { border: solid; }
```

```html
<table id="tableA">
        <tr>
            <td id="columnA">
            I want arial font here
            </td>
            <td id="columnB">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <table id="tableB">
        <tr>
            <td id="columnC">
            This should just be bold
            </td>
            <td id="ColumnD">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

However, if you really want to style *columns* (containing more than one cell), you need different techniques—either different `id` attributes for cells of a column all listed in `id` attributes for a rule or, more sensibly, `class` attributes for them and a class selector, or more advanced CSS selectors like `td:nth-child(2)` which let you style cells in a column even without `id` or `class` attributes. But if you have issues like this and some problems with them, please ask a new question.

Comment: Why does this work if i use .tableA and not #tableA?

Comment: @Mike, if you use `.tableA` as the selector of a rule, with the given markup, then that rule has no effect, since there is no class `tableA` set in the markup. If it seems to work, then your actual markup is different.

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

```
<head>
<style>
#columnA
{
  font-family: arial;
}
#columnC
{
  font-style: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score -4):

You should stay away from id's when doing css. Classes are defined like this:
`<table class="my-class-name">Content</table>`

Comment: OP: "can someone post a quick example of how to specify classes for tables."